# Is it possible to set a mac running MacOS Big Sur as a RDP (remote desktop protocol) host / server?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, xrdp

**Question :**

Is it possible to set a mac running MacOS Big Sur as a RDP (remote desktop protocol) host / server ? To be clear im looking for a Mac to Mac RDP solution not a Mac to Windows RDP, or Mac to Mac VNC / ARD solution. Any suggestions ?

**Background :**

RDP behaves quite differently to VNC (Virtual network computing) / ARD (Apple Remote Desktop), mainly in that RDP sends the information to be rendered into a graphical interface to the client, where as a VNC / ARD client views the host / servers pre rendered graphical output.

In practice this means that RDP can render a remote session to suit the client devices screen, where as VNC / ARD serve a pre rendered version of the host / servers screen to the client.

With RDP if you have a 15" laptop screen and connect to a host computer with a 32" screen, RDP will render a 15" wide GUI to suit your screen.

With VNC / ARD if you 15" laptop screen and connect to a host computer with a 32" screen, VNC / ARD will provide you with a scaled 32" interface on a 15" screen. Eg. it just zooms out to fit everything in, but this means everything is tiny and not really usable.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a 'server' as such. macOS has no limitation on the number of concurrently-connected users, nor the number of accounts they connect to.

Login as a different user [ie connect to a virtual display] rather than share the screen with the current user. You can then set up your own display resolution.

This is remoting to a Mac set to 1280x720 whilst the user sitting at it is still seeing it at 2560x1440

[image]

If your initial view is too small to see, you can temporarily change View mode to "Show Full Size" which will give you scroll bars [&/or scroll as the cursor reaches the edge] to navigate.

Comment: There's also the protocol though - VNC can be a bit crap , so its possible OP wants to run RDP specifically to connect to an RDP client

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - but there is no macOS RDP host. Other than this specific rescaling requirement, I can see no advantage to using RDP at all. ARP has far more admin-capable protocols than RDP [which is really only a screen-share, little more]

Comment: Slightly better client flexibility one would guess. And OP's explicitly said why they don't want ARP(ARD?) and VNC

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - well, the OP is asking for a software rec, which I've neatly skirted ;) Their requirement seems only to avoid the oversized display issue, there seems to be no other requirement except one leading from the false conclusion that ARD cannot resize the screen. I think we're probably best to wait for the OP to come back on this…